# how to remove '\' from string

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby.I have a string like

```
string = "You have successfully placed Service Request No. \#{@service_requests.id} for \#{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you."
```

and I want to remove "\" from whole string.

```
output_string = "You have successfully placed Service Request No. #{@service_requests.id} for #{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you."
```

How to make it possible.

Comment: You were given a correct answer to the problem “_how to remove backslashes from a string_,” and you commented with “it’s not working” below it. That means, you stated the problem improperly. Please describe in details what you have, what you need to do, what you are yielding and what is the problem. Downvoted for a meanwhile.

Comment: Actually I want to remove back slashes from string. Below some suggestions are not working for me. But @Зелёный answer is working properly so I upvoted

Comment: `"\#"` is not a backslash followed by a pound sign. Rather it is a single character, an escaped `"#"`, which is the same as an unescaped `"#"`: `"\#".size #=> 1; "\#" == "#" #=> true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> string = "You have successfully placed Service Request No. \#{@service_requests.id} for \#{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for
the same. Thank you."
>> puts(string)
=> You have successfully placed Service Request No. #{@service_requests.id} for #{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you.
>> puts(string.inspect)
=> "You have successfully placed Service Request No. \#{@service_requests.id} for \#{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you."
```

Make sure you know what the difference between string representation (`puts string.inspect`) and string content (`puts string`) is, and note the backslashes as the artifacts of the representation.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string.gsub(/\\/, '') # or string.gsub!(/\\/, '') for inplace substitution
```

Comment: This is return an Enumerator, you are missing the second argument.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that.

Comment: THIS IS NOT WORKING

Comment: Consider using `String#delete` instead of `String#gsub` to _remove single characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this like:

```
string.gsub(%r{\"}, '')
```

Comment: It is not working.Output is as it is.                                                            "You have successfully placed Service Request No. \#{@service_requests.id} for \#{@service_requests.category.name} . Our representative will be in touch with you soon for the same. Thank you."

Comment: this is working for me

Comment: "\" is not removing from output.

Comment: can you add space after backslash like  "Request No. \  #{@service_requests.id}"